# websharper for VS Express 2012

Tags: visual-studio-express, websharper

Is it possible to use WebSharper with VS Express 2012?

I read [Websharper templates for F# Tools for Visual Studio 2012 Express for Web](https://bitbucket.org/IntelliFactory/websharper/issue/90/websharper-templates-for-f-tools-for) and wanted to try. So I installed WebSharper, then found folder with WebSharper templates, but don't know where I should copy them.

Anybody tried?

Comment: In general, most add-ins do not work with the Express editions.

Comment: but project templates, are they add-ins? But I added for example http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/3d2bf938-fc9e-403c-90b3-8de27dc23095 successfully to VS Express.

Comment: Please put that as an answer, and not as an update.

Comment: I don't see textbox for answer.

Comment: okay, don't know why I didn't see Answer your question button, now I did it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found where you should put WebSharper templates. It should be in folder for project templates, specified in Tools -> Options -> Projects and Solutions -> General -> User project templates location:

[image]

After I copied templates there, they are available when I create new project.